# Determining whether an expression is less than or greater than zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, stationary-point

Let $x,n,$ and $\theta$ are greater than zero. How can I show whether the following quantity is greater than or less than zero?

$$\frac{n}{\theta^2}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}{\theta^3}$$

#### EDIT:

The quantity is actually a 2nd derivative of a function and I need to check that the stationary point is maximum. So, I have to show the quantity is less than $0$ everywhere.

Comment: $$\frac{n}{\theta^2}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}{\theta^3}  > 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \theta n - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 > 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \theta n > \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$$

Comment: @MattiP. The quantity is actually a 2nd derivative of a function and I need to check that the stationary point is maximum. So I have to show the quantity is less than $0$ everywhere.

Comment: Do you know anything about the value of $\sum x_i^2$?

Comment: @MattiP. I know that $\mathbb E(X_i^2)=2\theta,$ where $\mathbb E$ denotes expected value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).